# Store range of color values as array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get color values from a table in excel, store them as an array while I reorganize the table, and then put the color values back into the table. The following code works for values and number formats but not for color values. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Colors()
    Dim cArray As Variant
    Set Rng = Range("A1: T300")
    ReDim cArray(1 To Rng.Rows.Count, 1 To Rng.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
            cArray(i, j) = Rng(i, j).ColorValue
        Next j
    Next i
    Call SortTable
    Rng.ColorValue = cArray
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - wouldn't you need `Interior`? like  `cArray(i,j) = rng(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex`.

Comment: `rng(i, j).` + (choose one:) 1. `Font.` 2. `Border.` 3. `Interior.` + `ColorIndex`

Comment: @BruceWayne  You are correct!

Comment: Maybe you could use paste-special to copy the formats to an unused section of the spreadsheet, reorganize the table, and then paste the formats back. Also -- are you sure that there isn't a simple solution using the ListObject's `TableStyle` property?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `.ColorValue` is something recognized by VBA.  Instead, use `cArray(i,j) = rng(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex`.

Then, when you want to set a cell's color, just do `Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = [whatever]`.

[Here's a](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) pretty detailed page discussing `ColorIndex` and the HTML/Hex/RGB equivalents/related things.

Edit: I assumed you wanted the background color.  If you instead want the font color, it'd just be `cArray(i,j) = rng(i,j).Font.Color`.